# How to read only a section of a file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a log file that has what's known as a header section, and then the rest of it is a lot of data. The header section contains certain key value pairs that tells a db table information about said file.

One of my tasks is to parse out some of this header info. The other task is to go through the entire file and parse out counts of when certain strings occur. The later part I have a function for attched below:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
     time_data_count = 0
     while True:
        memcap = f.read(102400)
        #  f.seek(-tdatlength, 1)
        poffset_set = set(config_offset.keys())
        # need logic to check if key value exists 
        time_data_count += memcap.count(b'TIME_DATA')
        if len(memcap) <= 8:
            break
     if time_data_count > 20:
         print("time_data complete")
     else:
         print("incomplete time_data data")
     print(time_data_count)
```

The issue now with this is that it is not a line by line processing which would take a lot of time. I want to only get the first 50 lines of this log and then parse them. Then have the rest of the function go through the entire file without goign line by line and doing the counting parts.

Is it possible to extract the first 50 lines without going through the entire file?
The first 50 lines have header info of the form

ProdID: A785X

What I really need is to get the value of ProdID in that log file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read line-by-line for the first 50, by using a `for` loop or a list comprehension to just read the next line 50 times. This moves the read pointer down through the file, so when you call `.read()` or any other method, you'll not get anything you've already consumed. You can then process the rest as batch, or however else you need to:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    first_50_lines = [next(f) for _ in range(50)]  # first 50 lines
    remainder_of_file = f.read()                   # however much of the file remains
```

You can alternate various methods of reading the file, as long as the same file object (`f` in this case) is in play the entire time. Line-by-line, sized-chunk by chunk, or all at once (though `.read()` is always going to preclude further processing, on account of consuming the whole thing at once).

Comment: Wait, I see a list comprehension... How does that list comprehension move the read pointer? And how would it know what we mean by range? How does it know that 50 is lines as opposed to chars? Also what does "_" after the "for" and before the "in" do? @Green Cloak Guy

Comment: @edo101 File objects are a type of iterator. When you iterate over a file, each item it returns is one line from that file (this is explicitly defined behavior for the the type of object that files are - `[line for line in f]` is functionally identical to `f.readlines()`). Like all iterators, you can call `next()` on a file to get a single element out - this is one line. And files have the behavior that when you read _any information_, in any capacity, the 'read' pointer moves through the file. Same if you read 12 bytes, or 'up until the next `\n`', any individual byte will only be read once.

Comment: @edo101 I use `for _ in range(50)` just to count to 50 for the iteration - the comprehension calls `next()` fifty times in a row, and makes a list out of the results. As for the read pointer, it moves forward on its own whenever stuff is read from the file. You can use `f.seek()` to reset the read pointer to a specific point, if you want, but in the absence of that no part of the same file object will be read twice. It works the same way as a `Scanner` in Java might, in this respect.

Comment: So in that list comprehension, why do you have next(f). Is that telling it to move to the next item in f? And then, if so, why do you have a "_" after the for? And I suppose because a file object is an iterator, then 50 is seen as lines in the file? So when you say 50, you are in fact going up to 50 lines?

Comment: Also should I use the while statement block directly after the list comprehension?@Green Cloak Guy

Comment: @edo101 Files are iterable - rather than explaining, might be more helpful to [look up a guide on how iterators work in python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator). For files specifically, `next(f)` is functionally identical to `f.readline()`. The list comprehension is literally just to count to 50, because there's no other good way to do the same thing 50 times (read the next line, over and over). I use `_` as a placeholder variable name, because the syntax requires that there _is_ a variable, but I'm not going to actually use that variable for anything.

Comment: How do you know so much about readin files? And thank you for the iterator link.
Also, why is it faster to read files in buffered chunks as opposed to all at once? @Green Cloak Guy

Comment: @edo101 It's not _faster_ to read files in buffered chunks, necessarily. It's more memory-efficient, because you only have to load a certain amount of the file into memory at a time (very very large files, larger than the computer's available RAM, can cause problems if you try to read them all at once).

Comment: I just notice that for files acress the board like 50 MB and up, read(102400) gives me the best speed. Anything below that or above that is not as fast. I even tried read(1024000) but it was slower @Green Cloak Guy. Tested it on different Windows systems